# Not able to validate a Popup Overlay in my application

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception

I am using Selenium webdriver using Cucumber.

I have clicked a button which open up a popup box, containing few web elements within it. I need to perform few validations in this pop up box. But once the overlay popup is displayed, I am not able to validate it using  isDisplayed.

In the console, it display a Error message - java.lang.NullPointerException but I am not passing any value in any variable to validate this popup box.

My script is as below:

```
    public static void Popupbox() {
    searchbox = (Application_Pagexpath.popupboxheader).isDisplayed();

    try{
        Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();    }

    if(searchbox = True) {
    System.out.println("Popup is displayed"); } 
}
```

The xpaths I am using are correct and these work fine in the firebug. Can you help me understand why  I am seeing the Null pointer exception error and why Selenium is not able to validate this overlay popup.

The HTML for the overlay popup is as below:

```
div id="_paymentHistoryPortlet_WAR_EBillingWebportlet_:paybillHtyForm:dvAdvSearchOverlay" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ebillingAdvFltrOverlay ui-draggable ui-overlay-visible" style="width: auto; height: auto; left: 227.7px; top: 0px; visibility: visible; z-index: 1001;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="_paymentHistoryPortlet_WAR_EBillingWebportlet_:paybillHtyForm:dvAdvSearchOverlay_title" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="polite"
  div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-top"
    div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="height: auto;"
```

Comment: have you tried debugging your code and which line are you getting null pointer??

Comment: A NullPointerException is likely because it cannot determine .isDisplayed unless the web element itself is located.  Break that line into two lines: one to assign the web element and another to test isDisplayed, but only if web element is not null.  If it's null, it's safe to say it's not displayed.

Comment: Hi Ranjith, I was seeing the null pointer exception at the siDisplayed line only.

Comment: Bill, Thanks for looking into this and providing the solution. I spillted the line into 2 as your asked for - one to assign the web element and another to test isDisplayed. But it didnt worked in the first run. During the second run I increased the time in sleep thread to 5000 ms and it worked this time. Thanks again.